# Using Textures with compute and fragment shaders

Tags: c++, opengl, textures, fragment-shader, compute-shader

I'm trying to use a texture to store some data to pass between the compute shader where the data is calculated to the fragment shader where it is used.

I create the texture and fill it with empty values using:

```
GLuint texID;
glGenTextures(1, &texID);

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, 256, 256, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, NULL);
```

I then make it available to the compute shader using:

```
glBindImageTexture(0, texID, 0, GL_FALSE, 0, GL_WRITE_ONLY, GL_RGBA32F);
```

Heres the spec for this function so you can check I use the correct arguments: https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glBindImageTexture.xhtml

Then inside the compute shader I get the texture using:

```
layout(rgba32f) coherent uniform image2D Texture;
```

And I then set one of the values of the texture as a test:

```
 imageStore(Texture, ivec2(0,0), vec4(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 1.0));
```

Which should put that vec4 into the texture at the position (0,0).

Then add the texture as a uniform for the program which the fragment shader belongs to:

```
GLint uniformID = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "Texture");
glUniform1i(uniformID, 0);
```

Then in the fragment shader I get ahold of the texture:

```
uniform sampler2D Texture;
```

And attempt to set somethings colour as the value in the texture at position (0,0):

```
color = texture2D(Texture, ivec(0,0));
```

However as a result I just get black: i.e (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0). I always get this regardless of what I set in the compute shader.

I am probably missing something really obvious so a bit of code showing what I'm missing would be great

Comment: Could you post the shaders you are using?